# Python decorator @property behaviour in class

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have a question about @property behaviour in a class's `__init__` function.
Here is the simplified code for example:

```py
class a:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ccc = None
        self._aaa = None
        self.bbb = None
        self.ddd = None

    @property
    def aaa(self):
        print('excuting aaa method')
        self.bbb = 'bbb'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = a() # break-point
    print(test.bbb)
    print(test.aaa)
```

I step into the code in debug mode and when it runs into `__init__` method, I see two attributes in the console(Please see pic1).

I know that `@property` decrator treats the function as an attrbute and can help to access an attribute without changing risk.

My question is why the decorated funtion seems to be executed at the very beginning in `__init__` function?

And if it runs at the beginning, it doesn't execute the print code inside aaa function when I run this code in normal run mode.

My guess is `@property` change the method as an attribute so when the class'es code executes, the decorated function runs impcility without any stdout.

Is that correct? or please inform me if I have anything misunderstood.

Pic1.
[image]

Comment: No, `aaa` isnt called/accessed implicitly in `__init__`. I'm not sure what the debugger is trying to say.

Comment: Probably the debugger is evaluating all attributes of the object, including properties, to show you a useful debug representation of the object. Since getters should be save to evaluate at any time, it doesn't refrain from doing so.